# Xamarin Forms Scrollview always scrolls

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have a ScrollView that contains a vertical StackLayout that, in turn, contains a ListView.  The ListView scrolls even when the list view is empty.  Is there a way to enable scrolling only when warranted or am I doing something wrong? I'm using data binding to populate the ListView.  Thanks.

Comment: You will need to add some code, particularly around the data binding to the  list view as this is the likely cause of your issue.

Comment: Consider restructuring your layout. Any srcollable-inside-scrollable setup is always asking for trouble and more often than not - a poor UI choice

Comment: Sten,  good point, the ScrollView is redundant and is now gone, unfortunately it still scrolls. Jordan, any suggestions for what to change about the data binding?  Thank you both.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not setted StackLayout's VerticalOptions Fill or FillAndExpand ?

Comment: I do not.  Just checked.  No VerticalOptions at all.